# New data tags in latest blogger theme

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I am unfamiliar with latest blogger theme, I want to create own template and markups. Do you know unpublished data tags in latest blogger template (Contempo, Soho, Emporio)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no official documentation for the new themes launched by Blogger.

Instead, I would suggest referring to http://template-data.blogspot.com/ and https://so-how-do-i.blogspot.com/. Both these blogs are maintained by a Blogger Engineering team member (Luke Bjerring) and contain quite a lot of information regarding the new themes code

Answer (score 0):

[Prayag Verma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43781603/399759) with links to the two blogs are the most comprehensive information. Google's official documentation now has

- [Layout data tags](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en)
- [Widget tags for layout](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969)